# How to deserialize text to String if it contains JSON data?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have generic code that does deserialization. It happen that content is indeed JSON data of some serialized object and GSON throws exception "expected String but was BEGIN_OBJECT"

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Class<T> type = String.class;
    String text= "{\"OrderId\":999,\"OrderDate\":\"Jan 11, 2015 12:00:00 AM\",\"Amount\":111.222,\"Comment\":\"order1\"}";
    T next = gson.fromJson( text, type);
```

In this case it looks like deserialization depends on the content rather than type provided to fromJson() method. I.e. it works well if text="foo" but failed if text="{foo}"

Question: how correctly deserialize text to String if it contains JSON data?

Comment: A JSON string maps to a Java `String`. You don't have a JSON string, you have a JSON object.

Comment: To Sotirios Delimanolis: Where did I say that I have "JSON string"?

Comment: It's implied when you provide a `String.class` as the deserialization target. What do you want the value of `next` to be?

Comment: I need it to be String

Comment: Value of the text is indeed serialized object but I need it as String. I.e. _next_ should be the same as _text_

Comment: It already is a `String`, in `text`.

Comment: Correct. But  fragment is generic code that deserializes variety of types. One type happen to have _String_ field with JSON in it. Generic code failed to deserialize.

Comment: Then your question is unclear. Are you just trying to get a field of a jdon object which is a json string? Please edit your questions with relevant details, sample input and output.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to deserialize an object into a String. You have specified that the JSON represents a String; however, it represents an Object with 4 fields. You should create an object that represents the data in the JSON, for instance:

```
public class OrderData{
  public int OrderId;
  public String OrderDate;
  public float Amount;
  public String Comment;
}
```

Then set type to OrderData.class instead. GSON will take the fields in the JSON object and store their values into a Java Object. `next` will be a OrderData object. I pick int and float as a best guess, if you were to change them to String, GSON would handle that automatically.

With that said, you should keep in mind 2 things for which the internet is filled with explanations:

- It is possible to have GSON deserialize the `OrderDate` into say a `Calendar` object instead
- You shouldn't use a float for money values as the spec for a float does not guarantee accuracy (e.g. 1.01 could become 1.01000000000001).